# Is there a RPM implementation out there other than librpm?

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpmbuild

Apparently all the newer stuff in the current RPM format is not really documented that well. Has somebody implemented **writing** RPMs other than the librpm?

Alternatively some pointers to the newer features of RPM would be helpful as well. Specifically the handling of the field with Tag 62 is very confusing for us.

**Notice**: This is not a question about how to use rpmbuild, I want to know more about the file format of RPM files!

Comment: Tag #62 introduces a signature header in modern (like last 10y) rpm. The tag is followed by a trailer with identical information and a negative offset to locate Tag #62 beginning. In between are the index and data store. What is usually tricky with the signature header is the padding to ensure that the metadata header (tag #63) is aligned on an 8b boundary. What is also tricky is certain of the tango identifiers have the same numbering as tags in the metadata header.

Comment: If you have a look at the blog entry (https://dentrassi.de/2016/04/15/writing-rpm-files-in-plain-java/) you'll see that Jens found your mailing list entry eventually. But thanks for showing up and explaing it here!

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found a java implementation here https://github.com/craigwblake/redline

And now as part of package drone Jens managed to create a implementation as well: https://dentrassi.de/2016/04/15/writing-rpm-files-in-plain-java/

Which resulted in the following maven plugin: http://ctron.github.io/rpm-builder/index.html#

Answer (score 0):

Well the documentation of changes and planned changes are now much better than used to be (IMHO) and is documented on http://www.rpm.org/#News and announced an properly discussed on rpm mailing lists. However there is always space for improvements and I agree that the binary format of rpm header can be documented better. You will have better chance to change something if you ask here: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Communicate#MailingLists

And back to your question, no - I'm not aware of any other implementation than librpm.